# Can I use cloth simulation to make a stand-up pouch similar to how you make a chip bag?

Tags: cloth-simulation

I like how the cloth simulation works for making chip bags:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gNh1m0pmUpE
I'm trying to figure out if I can make a stand-up pouch in a similar way. I've modeled it by hand previously, but I'd love to use the cloth simulation for it and I can't figure out how to handle the bottom of the package when I'm setting up the simulation[image: Stand up pouch]

Comment: the problem why nobody is answering might be the fact that it sounds like you are searching for someone to do your work. So to be a good citizen and prove that you at least tried something, pls add your blend file with at least the model and cloth simulation you tried, i will help you then. But i am too lazy to rebuild everything on my own. And you want free help from us in our spare time, so you should make it as easy as possible for us to help you. thx.

Comment: so sorry. I wasn't sure how hard this is to answer. i tried a bunch of things and am having a hard time figuring out the best way to do it. I tried just building it manually, then I experimented with the cloth effect, then learned about simulating thicker cloth both with including something "within" a thick cloth, and with using the cloth effect at a much smaller scale. I can attach some of my test files, but they are just in random spots of working, so not sure how helpful they are other than showing that I'm trying. Hope this is okay, here are my test files so far

Comment: Hope this is okay, here are my test files so far https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j2j5PcNX1OAk9br7YUpfJot9EL7UJukH/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I ended up doing it by hand